# php compose link dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to compose a link like this one:

> https://123reduceri.ro/api/v2/bucuresti.json?token=f65c060dc913a75e446cffb53653ba89b39b4852&sids%5B%5D=&sids[]=1&sids[]=2&sids[]=4

where sids[]=1 etc , this ids are taken dynamically , as an sql result.
my question is: how can i get them in the url? i tried with:

```
$apiCategoryUrl = 'https://123reduceri.ro/api/v2/bucuresti.json?'.
                  'token=f65c060dc913a75e446cffb53653ba89b39b4852&sids%5B%5D&'.
                  foreach ($pageposts as $pp): 
                      echo 'sids[]='.$pp.'&'; 
                  endforeach;   ?>;
```

but it is not okay.. any ideas?

Comment: Whats the output you get? do a print_r on the contents of $pageposts to make sure you're retrieving ok.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function

```
$url_root = "https://123reduceri.ro/api/v2/bucuresti.json?";

$params = array(
    "token" => "f65c060dc913a75e446cffb53653ba89b39b4852",
    "sids"  => array(1,2,3,4,5)
);

$url = $url_root . http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: thank you, but i must keep the sid[] string which is not in the array

Answer (score 2):

you are echo'ing the sid's, not adding them to the string ...

```
$apiCategoryUrl = "https://https://123reduceri.ro/api/v2/bucuresti.json?token=f65c060dc913a75e446cffb53653ba89b39b4852&sids%5B%5D&";

foreach ($pageposts as $pp) {
    $apiCategoryUrl .= "sids[]=".$pp."&";
}

echo $apiCategoryUrl;
```

Comment: no problem - it's easily overlooked when you are debugging. would you mind accepting? :)